# PHP File Forbidden Access on Localhost

Tags: php, html, apache, xampp

I am trying to open a simple `Hello World` `php` file. But every time I try and run the file on my `localhost` server I get the following message. I have even tried editing the `httpd-xampp.conf` in the `apache` folder in `xampp` granting all but with no luck.

## Error Message

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.`
>
> Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/8.0.10 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: "granting all" - well, that's basically what you need to do. So, you may have put it in the wrong place? Applied it to the wrong directory? Used the wrong directive? You need to include the relevant vHost / server config to debug this further.

Answer (score 2):

Open your apache configuration file and grant access for the directory that the php file is located in, example

```
<Directory "/folder/subfolder/noob/subfolder">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for us to diagnose your problem without inspecting your server configuration, but (assuming you have PHP installed okay) as a stop gap to get you up and running until you figure out this problem, you can use the built in PHP webserver. Open a command prompt or terminal in the directory where you want your document root to be and enter the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then navigate to http://localhost:8000 in your browser.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php